# algorithm of turning a distorted rectangle back to normal

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I am thinking a way to transform a distorted rectangle back to normal but I have no idea how. I cannot find any information about it as well. Could anyone provide some information about how to do the trick only knowing the x, y position of the 4 junctions? Known the rectangle was 640 x 480 before distorted.[image: Example of the distorted rectangle][image: Example2]

I think the problem can be solved by finding the transformation matrix in linear algebra. Since there is information about the original and the final matrix.

Comment: this is a skew problem not a transformation problem

Comment: If you could calculate the area bounded by the original rectangle, all you'd have to do is shift x&y positions until you got an unskewed rectangle with the same area. Heck you could probably cheat and just draw a new rectangle.

Comment: You need to post your attempt of solving this problem (the advice I gave above may be of help). Is this homework?

Comment: With the lose definition of what the target rectangle is, compute the [area  of the quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Area_of_a_convex_quadrilateral) and form a square with the same area - done.

Comment: Until you define the set of possible distortions, the problem will not have any meaningful solution. Who knows what the original rectangle looked like? *Any* rectangle can be "distorted" into the one in your example.

Comment: My apology for the missing information. The original rectangle is fix one 640x480. I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason Liu - describing the original rectangle is insufficient.   There are many possible transformations that can turn a particular rectangle into a particular "distorted" figure.   Unless you specify the set of possible transformations and order in which multiple transformations might be performed, your question has no unique solution.    And, BTW, your questions is about an algorithm - the tagging as C or C++ is irrelevant.

Comment: @Peter, I have seen some software that can turn a distorted cheque picture back to normal. I was looking some algorithm that can do the trick.

Comment: The question is now turned into finding the transformation matrix for given original matrix and the matrix after transformation I think.

Answer (score 1):

You have coordinates of 4 corners of distorted rectangle and want to transform it to some rectangle. In this case you need **perspective transformation**. Just define points for resulting rectangle as you want (for example, unit square in coordinate origin).

Now you have 8 pairs of corresponding parameters (x and y for every point), and need to calculate 8 parameters of matrix using 8 equations

```
 //four pairs of such equations:
 x' = (A * x + B * y + C) / (G * x + H * y + 1.0)
 y' = (D * x + E * y + F) / (G * x + H * y + 1.0)
```

Theory of finding perspective transformation matrix is described in [Paul Heckbert article](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2008_fall/Papers/proj.pdf).

C++ implementation could be found in [antigrain library](http://www.antigrain.com/agg-2.5.zip) (file agg_trans_perspective.h)

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenCV.

sample tip

```
Point lt = Point(200, 40) ;
Point rt = Point(500, 44) ;
Point rb = Point(740, 355) ;
Point lb = Point(30, 200) ;

vector<Point> rect ;
rect.push_back(lt) ;
rect.push_back(rt) ;
rect.push_back(rb) ;
rect.push_back(lb) ;

double w1 = sqrt(pow(rb.x-lb.x, 2)+pow(rb.y-lb.y, 2)) ;
double w2 = sqrt(pow(rt.x-lt.x, 2)+pow(rt.y-lt.y, 2)) ;
double h1 = sqrt(pow(rb.x-rt.x, 2)+pow(rb.y-rt.y, 2)) ;
double h2 = sqrt(pow(lb.x-lt.x, 2)+pow(lb.y-lt.y, 2)) ;
double maxW = (w1<w2)? w2 : w1 ;
double maxH = (h1<h2)? h2 : h1 ;

Point2f src[4], dst[4] ;
src[0]=Point2f(lt.x, lt.y) ;
src[1]=Point2f(rt.x, rt.y) ;
src[2]=Point2f(rb.x, rb.y) ;
src[4]=Point2f(lb.x, lb.y) ;

dst[0]=Point2f(0,0) ;
dst[1]=Point2f(maxW, 0) ;
dst[2]=Point2f(maxW, maxH) ;
dst[3]=Point2f(0, maxH) ;

tfMat = getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst) ;
wrapPerspective(srcImage, dstImage, trMat, Size(maxW, maxH)) ;
```